# Subtracting loop elements

Tags: c, subtraction

I want to subtract `i` from `total` in the `for` loop below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc,const char *argv[]){

    int total = 0;
    int i;
    for(i = 10; i > 0; i--){
        // code
    }
    printf("Total: %d\n",total);
    return 0;
}
```

The expected output is be -35.

How I can do that?

Comment: Too vague to answer.  If you want to subtract `i` from `total`, use `total -= i;`  If not, then you need to be more specific.

Comment: @TomKarzes I used total -= i; but result is incorrect

Comment: And what did you expect the result to be?

Comment: @user3386109 I expect the result must be −35

Comment: And why would 10 subtractions result in an answer of -35?

Comment: @user3386109 10-9-8-7-6-5-4-3-2-1  = - 35 like this

Comment: Ah, then Mohan was almost right, but `total` needs to start at `10`, and `i` needs to start at `9`.

Comment: @user3386109 thanks bro )

Answer (score 2):

May be what you expect

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc,const char *argv[]){

    int total = 10;  //initialised for example
    int i ;
    for(i = 9; i > 0; i--){  
        total -= i;   //Subtracttion total  = total - i ;
    }
    printf("Total: %d\n",total);
    return 0;
}
```